# Break Condition on COM Port Open

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port

I have an application developed in C that opens a COM port and sends data. This works fine and has done for years.

Now I have one user where it behaves incorrectly. On their PC when my code opens the COM port it generates a break condition. It does this until 11ms before the first byte of data is transmitted at which point the transmit goes back to logic 1. So it is:

- COM port open
- Break condition for a period of time
- Break condition ends
- 11ms later first start bit appears.

When they use a third-party terminal program on the same PC it doesn't generate a break condition when opening the COM port.

I double-checked on my PC and sure enough the transmit signal stays at logic 1 until the first start bit, as expected.

I have no reports of this problem from other users. This particular user is using a COM port from a laptop docking station.

I configure the COM port using SetCommState and SetupComm. I call ClearCommError and PurgeComm at the end of initialization. I use CreateFile to open the port.

Here is the port configuration I am using:

```
mydcb.fBinary = TRUE;
mydcb.fParity = FALSE;
mydcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
mydcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
mydcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
mydcb.fOutX = FALSE;
mydcb.fInX = FALSE;
mydcb.fNull = FALSE;
mydcb.Baudrate = 19200;
mydcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
mydcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
mydcb.ByteSize = 8;
mydcb.fAbortOnError = FALSE;
mydcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
mydcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
```

COM port open:

```
comport = CreateFile(resourcename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
  NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
```

Does this problem ring any bells with anyone? Are there any hints or suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Laptops often have trouble generating an RS-232 compatible voltage.  An imperfect charge pump can well look like a break signal to the receiver for example.  This is surely a hardware problem, use an oscilloscope to diagnose, not your problem.

Comment: It seems strange that the third-party terminal program doesn't do this, making me think I can tweak something in my code to avoid it.

Comment: Does that emulator actually indicate a break condition in an easy to recognize way?  When you can't repro then you're relying on a very imperfect source of information of course.

Comment: The break condition was observed with a logic analyser, in the same way for both my code and for the third-party terminal program. Yes, not being able to rerpo is a pain...

Comment: If your customer tells you he is using a 'logic analyzer' then he's just telling you a story.  An oscilloscope is the proper tool, hooked up to your RxD input.  Voltage should never be less than +/- 5V.  Cycling power is important to repro a problem with a charge pump.

Comment: The logic analyser is connected to the TTL UART pins on a microcontroller. The hardware in use is identical when testing with my code and with the terminal program. RS232 transceiver is in use of course.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll try donning my Captain Obvious hat.

Did you try using the [`EscapeCommFunction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call to explicitly *clear* the break state of the port, right after opening it? Perhaps the UART drivers on that particular user's machine are buggy, so why not be epxlicit about what you want.

Comment: Just tried it. Called EscapeCommFunction with CLRBREAK immediately after CreateFile. Sadly it didn't have any effect. :( Good suggestion though and I'll leave it in my code anyway!